# need help filtering out Oracle results

Tags: sql, oracle

i wish i could show you my full Oracle SQL query but i can't.... but its set up something like this

```
SELECT
  TABLE1.TEST
  TABLE2.SUB_TEST
  TABLE3.RUN_NAME
FROM
  TABLE1
  TABLE2
  TABLE3
  TABLE4
WHERE
  *just some LIKE statements to search for what i want*
```

anyways, let's say it returns something like this.

```
TEST    SUB_TEST    RUN_NAME
TEST1   SUBTEST1   49_4021
TEST1   SUBTEST2   49_4021
TEST1   SUBTEST1   49_4033
TEST1   SUBTEST2   49_4033
TEST2   SUBTEST1   50_2122
TEST2   SUBTEST2   50_2122
```

Each TEST has two or more SUBTESTs. each time a TEST is run, it creates a RUN_NAME which is a number that is incremented by an unknown amount. eachtime a TEST is run, each SUBTEST has the same RUN_NAME.

my question, in this example, TEST1 is run twice, and i was wondering, how can i make it so it only returns to the result of bigger RUN_NAME. Note, i still want it to return TEST2 along with TEST1, but i only want to return the results of the bigger RUN_NAME for TEST1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want `MAX(RUN_NAME)` to me:

```
SELECT TEST, SUB_TEST, MAX(RUN_NAME) as RUN_NAME
FROM yourTables
WHERE yourConditions
GROUP BY TEST, SUB_TEST
```

This will output:

```
TEST    SUB_TEST    RUN_NAME
TEST1   SUBTEST1   49_4033
TEST1   SUBTEST2   49_4033
TEST2   SUBTEST1   50_2122
TEST2   SUBTEST2   50_2122
```

Actually, if the `SUBTESTS` are different and don't group, you will want `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TEST, SUB_TEST, RUN_NAME, 
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TEST, SUB_TEST ORDER BY RUN_NAME DESC) RN
      FROM yourTables
      WHERE yourConditions) A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: thanks! this worked!!! can you explain a bit on how this works? I understand what GROUP BY does, just not how MAX relates to it? EDIT: nevermind, i can't believe i didn't think of this.... thanks!!! your awesome and i hope you have a great day!

Comment: @pts2800 Sure, I can try - Think of it like this, if you simply grouped by all the fields, without an aggregate like `MAX()`, they would not "roll-up" into a single row, because there are different `RUN_NAME`s.  In order to deal with this, you want to *choose* which `RUN_NAME` to display when there are more than one.  In this case you said you want the largest `RUN_NAME`, which in SQL terms is `MAX(RUN_NAME)`.  Hopefully that helps a bit.